# Linux sort command: keys with the same start but different length are not sorted in the same order

Tags: linux, sorting, command-line-arguments

I am trying to sort two files in order to join them. Some of the keys I am sorting by are very similar and this seems to be causing issues. For example I have two keys which are `a1ke` and `a1k3-b3`. I am using the command:

```
sort -nk1 file.txt -o file.txt
```

In one file they appear in this order and in the other they appear in reverse. This is causing issues when I try to join the files.

How can I sort these files so they are in the same order?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the "-n" option, which compares according to the string numerical value.

```
-n
Compare according to arithmetic value an initial numeric string consisting of optional white
space, an optional - sign, and zero or more digits, optionally followed by a decimal point and
zero or more digits.
```

Your keys are strings, not numbers.

Instead, you should just do:

```
sort -k1 file.txt -o file.txt
```

**Additional info:**

You can see that `sort` considers your keys identical when `-n` is used by doing a unique sort:

```
sort -un file
```

You will see that `a1k3-b3` and `a1ke` are considered equal (and therefore only one is emitted).  If instead you do:

```
sort -u file
```

The result will contain both `a1k3-b3` and `a1ke`, which is what you want.

Comment: In previous file editing I did a unique sort on one of the files and those keys are still there. Besides I want to keep both, is there any way to do that and have a uniform ordering?

Comment: @LeeAnn I'm not suggesting you do a unique sort for real.  I'm only suggesting that you try it to see that `a1k3-b3` and `a1ke` are considered identical keys when the `-n` option is used, but not when it is omitted.  I'll clarify my answer.